# Exponential function as a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have to prove that exponential function is equals to $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for $x<0$, I have the part for positive numbers, any help for this part? maybe something with $-x>0$ and $e^{-x}=\dfrac{1}{e^x}$ and Cauchy product?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^m}{m!}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\sum_{m=0}^{\infty }  \frac{(-1)^nx^{n+m}}{n!m!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\sum_{j=0}^{k }  \frac{(-1)^jx^{k}}{j!(k-j)!}
\qquad n+m=k,\ j=n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k }  \frac{(-1)^jk!}{j!(k-j)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k }  (-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\\
&=1
\qquad\text{since }\sum_{j=0}^{k }  (-1)^j\binom{k}{j}=0
\text{ for }k \ge 1\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^m}{m!}
=e^x
$
for $x \ge 0
$,
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}
=\frac1{e^x}
=e^{-x}
$
for $x \ge 0
$.

Of course,
in the same way,
you can show that
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{y^m}{m!}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(x+y)^n}{n!}
$.

Comment: But I don't understad exactly how what you said me...help me for the proof.

Comment: I don't understand how it can help me in the proof...